# CSS Selector in R

Tags: css, r

I need to scrape the depreciation value off the "kelly blue book" site.

I am having a lot of trouble figuring out the CSS selector. The following code has at least produced a number (everything else I tried didn't give me any output at all) but the number is wrong.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
library('rvest')
url<- 'https://www.kbb.com/ford/escape/2019/se-ownershipcostsmodal/? 
vehicleid=439775&ctomileage=15000'
webpage<- read_html(url)
price_html<-html_nodes(webpage,'.mod-title.right')
price<-html_text(price_html)
head(price)
Ford_depreciation<- data.frame( Price = price )
write.table(Ford_depreciation)
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: I get a value of `$18,660` by running your code. Isn't it the output?

Comment: I get 18,972.  The webpage says 18246 though.

Comment: I got $18,699 which looks the same as the figure on the page currently...

Comment: For a 2019 Ford Escape?  Thats the car I need to get the info on.  Definitely says 18246 when I look.  So strange...

Comment: Yes, for 2019 Ford Escape SE Sport Utility 4-door

Comment: Could be a bit different based on your location too.

Comment: I see 18,461 so you different